# Model a large MongoDB collection that rarely updates

Tags: mongodb, database-design

**Context:**

I'm currently modeling data which follow a deep tree pattern consisting of 4 layers (categories, subcategories, subsubcategories, subsubsubcategories... those two lasts are of course not the real words I'll be using)
This collection is meant to grow larger and larger over time, and each layer will contain a list of dozens of elements.

**Problem:**

Modeling a full embedded collection like that raises a big problem ; the 16MB document limit of MongoDB is not really ideal in this context because the document size will slowly approach the limit.

But at the same time, this data is not meant to be updated very often (at most a few times a day). Client-side, the API needs to return a fully-constructed big JSON file made of all those layers nested together. It can be easily made in such a way that every time a layer is updated, the full JSON result is updated too and stored in RAM, ready to be sent.

I was wondering if having a 4 layers tree like that split in different collections would be a better idea, because at the same time it would raises more queries, but it would be way more scalable and easy to understand. But I don't really know if it's the way MongoDB documents are meant do be modeled. I may be doing something wrong (first time using MongoDB) and I want to be sure that everything is already in this way of doing things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest you to take a look at official [MongoDB tree structures](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/) advices, and especially the solution with parent reference. It will allow you to keep your structure without struggling of the 16MB maximum size, and you can use [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) aggregation stages to perform your further queries on tree subdocuments